# Parent child relation in Linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In the Entity Class

I have two parent table "TestParent" and "TestTag" in Entity class and one of the child table 
"TestChild" which is not updated in Entity class. so can I Join the TestParent and TestChild table (both are foreinkey primary relation).

Issue: I am not able to select child table TestChild in Linq query

Table : TestTag:

[image]

Table: TestParent:

[image]

Childtable: TestChild

[image]

In Entity class below

```
public DbSet<TestParent> Questions { get; set; }
  public DbSet<TestTag> Tags { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is <Question> related to `TestParent`? If not, please provide `TestParent` Entity class? Also I am not seeing any relationship between `TestParent` and `TestChild`.

Comment: @BijayKoirala, sorry I have Updated  pls check it

Comment: One more thing, did u forget to `update TestChild` since I do not see how `TestTag, TestParent and  TestChild` are related?

Comment: pls assume  In the TestChild table ->  TagId is the   Primary key of the  TestParent table. I mean TestParent and TestChild table gave Foreign key prime key relation.  TestTag table there is no any relation.

Comment: Then, you cannot achieve join from the `Linq`. If you are not planning to modify the Entity Class to Add `TestChild` then you can create the `store procedure` where you can do the join and the get the data from the code calling the `sp`.

Comment: If I change relation like 
In the TestChild table  TagId is the Primary Key of the TestTag table and QuestionId is the Primary Key of the TestParent Table .then Is it possible  join the TestChild table  in Linq query without adding TestChild table  in Entity class. 
Is there any  select query in linq. I need to select records from TestParent table  based on TagId which I passing the value in to the TestChild Table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188463/discussion-between-sajith-and-bijay-koirala).

Answer (score 0):

So you have three tables: a table of `TestTags`, a table of `TestParents` and a table with `TestChildren`.

Every `TestTag` has zero or more `TestChildren`; every `TestChild` belongs to exactly one `TestTag`, using a foreign key. A straightforware one-to-many relation

Every `TestParent` also has zero or more `TestChildren`; every `TestChild` has exactly one `TestParent`, using a foreign key.

If you followed the [entity framework code first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), you would have something similar to

```
class TestTag
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...  // other properties

    // every TestTag has zero or more TestChildren (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<TestChild> TestChildren {get; set;}
}
class TestParent
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...  // other properties

    // every TestParent has zero or more TestChildren (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<TestChild> TestChildren {get; set;}
}
class TestChild
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...  // other properties

    // every TestChild has exactly one TestParent using foreign key
    public int TestParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual TestParent TestParent {get; set;}

    // every TestChild has exactly one TestTag using foreign key
    public int TestTagId {get; set;}
    public virtual TestTag TestTag {get; set;}
}
```

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

This way it is possible for TestTag 4 and TestParent 5 to have two Children. If you don't want, consider creating a combined primary key [TestTagId, TestParentId]

If TestChild has no other properties than the foreign keys, than in fact you are creating a many-to-many relation between TestTag and TestParent. In that case you don't have to mention the TestChild table.

For completeness the DbContext:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<TestTag> TestTags {get; set;}
     public DbSet<TestParent> TestParents {get; set;}
     public DbSet<TestChild> TestChildren {get; set;}
}
```

This is all that entity framework needs to know to detect your relations and the primary and foreign keys. Because I followed the conventions attributes nor fluent API is necessary, except maybe because of the non-standard plural form `Children`.

> so can I Join the TestParent and TestChild table

Well you can do a (group-)join, but it is usually easier to use the `ICollections`

**Give me the TestParents that ... with all their TestChildren and TestTags that ...**

```
var result = dbContext.TestParents
    .Where(parent => ...)             // if you don't want all testParents
    .Select(parent => new
    {
        // select only the properties you plan to use
        Id = parent.Id,
        Name = parent.Name,

        Children = parent.TestChildren
            .Where(child => child.TestTag.Name = "My Test Tag Name")
            .Select(child => new
            {
                Name = child.TestTag.Name,
                ...
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

Some people prefer to do a GroupJoin instead. If you want that, and you can convince your project leader that a GroupJoin is better readable / testable / maintainable than using the ICollections, you can do the following:

```
var result = dbContext.TestParents.GroupJoin(dbContext.TestChildren,
    parent => parent.Id,                // from each parent take the Id
    child => child.ParentId,            // from each child take the ParentId

    // resultSelector:
    (parent, children) => new
    {
        // Parent Properties:
        Id = parent.Id,
        ...

        // GroupJoin the collection of child properties with the TestTags:
        children.GroupJoin(dbContext.TestTags,
        child => child.TestTagId,          // from each TestChild take the TestTagId
        tag => tag.Id,                     // from each TestTag take the Id
        (child, tagsOfThisChild) => new
        {
            // desired Child properties
            ...

            TestTags = tagsOfThisChild.Select(tag => new
            {
                 Id = tag.Id,
                 ...
            })
            .ToList(),
        })
        .ToList(),
    });
```

IMHO: this looks horrible!

Comment: I need to only return "TestParents"  table records based on the "TestChild" table TagId. I will be passing "tagId"